# Calcular o tempo que um carro esteve estacionado

Tags: c

Estou a ler um ficheiro `parque.txt` que contém as horas que um carro esteve num parque de estacionamento, do tipo `"9h00 10h30"`, isto em cada linha.

Estava a tentar obter essas horas em cada bloco de *char*, neste caso teria `hora_i="9", min_i="00", hora_f="10", min_f="30"`, o problema é que no `printf` final ele mostra `hora_i="9", min_i="009", hora_f="10009", min_f="3010009"`.

Já experimentei a fazer `fflush(stdin)`, mas não resultou...

```
void calcula_estacionamento()
{
    FILE *f;
    int n=0,i=0;
    char linha[MAX],hora_i[2]="",min_i[2]="",hora_f[2]="",min_f[2]="";
    f=fopen("parque.txt","r");
    while(fgets(linha,MAX,f)!=NULL)
    {
        while(linha[n]!='h')
        {
            hora_i[i]=linha[n];
            n++;
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        n++;
        while(linha[n]!=' ')
        {
            min_i[i]=linha[n];
            n++;
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        n++;
        while(linha[n]!='h')
        {
            hora_f[i]=linha[n];
            n++;
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        n++;
        while(linha[n]!='\0')
        {
            min_f[i]=linha[n];
            n++;
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n%s %s %s %s",hora_i,min_i,hora_f,min_f);
        n=0;
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltaram os [caracteres nulos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere_nulo#O_car.C3.A1cter_nulo_e_a_representa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_de_strings:) (`\0`) em cada uma das suas strings. Ou seja, cada um dos seus vetores deve possuir até 3 caracteres:

```
char linha[MAX], hora_i[3] = "", min_i[3] = "", hora_f[3] = "", min_f[3] = "";
```

É importante que você termine todas as string corretamente durante a leitura do seu código

```
hora_i[i] = '\0';
i=0;
// ...
min_i[i] = '\0';
i=0;
// ...
hora_f[i]= '\0';
i=0;
// ...
min_f[i]= '\0';
```

Finalmente, se você realmente for ler múltiplas linhas de um arquivo, é importante prever tanto o fim do arquivo quanto o fim de uma linha:

```
while(linha[n]!='\0' && linha[n]!='\n') 
{ 
    // ...
```

**[Exemplo funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/bC16gY)**

---

#### Pontos importantes que eu não pude incluir no exemplo

Faltou o tratamento de erros na hora de abrir o arquivo:

```
f=fopen("parque.txt","r");
if(f == NULL) {
    perror("Erro abrindo o arquivo");
    return(-1);
}
```

Bem como o tratamento para fechá-lo:

```
fclose(f);
```

Comment: obrigado, agora resolveu o erro, não me lembrei desse pormenor do '\0' para finalizar a string... eu quando faço apenas read de ficheiros não costumo fazer fclose(), não sei se é boa política, mas eu faço assim

Comment: Sem problemas Miguel, fico feliz em ter ajudado. Sobre arquivos (e ponteiros em geral), minha dica é: sempre que alocar algo já digite o código para fechar :). Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema não se esqueça de aceitá-la.